# Zend framework autoload base controller?

Tags: zend-framework, controller

How do i autoload a base controller in Zend?

Something like:

```
class Default_AdminUserController extends Application_Component_AdminController{}
```

Just does not work :D setting and extra include path in the .ini does not work also. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had understand that your project structure might be something like that :

```
    /zfproject
     /application
       /controller/.............
       /models/................
       /views/.................
       /component   // this is where you want to save your base controller 
       /etc ..............
     /public/...........
     /library/.........
```

if i am right so you are trying to load what is called in ZF as `resource`
and some examples here .... http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/learning.autoloading.resources.html

base controller is an old idea , i had read about it more than 1.5 Year in Cal Evans book : [guide to zend framework programming](http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-programming-with-zend-framework/)
and i'd highly recommend  to stick with ZF plugins instead of the base controller

Comment: and this might help http://phpdev.ro/zf-tutorial-series-part-1-module-based-app.html

Comment: +1 for using controller plugins and action helpers instead of extending a base controller

Comment: Yes i have gone with the plugins too.. base controllers do not seem well supported with zend framework.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a class such as that to autoload it would have to be named:

`[your include path]/Application/Component/AdminController.php`

Typically for base classes such as this most people will have a 'library' path within their application and have that added to the include path and then follow Zend Framework's naming conventions so the autoloader *just works*.